# How to show success message after insertion through form submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to show success message when insertion is complete.Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string txthospitalname, int city)
{
    var hospitals = new Hospital()
    {
        Name = txthospitalname,
        FKCityID = city,
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = 1,
    };
    _db.Hospitals.Add(hospitals);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

**View.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Hospital", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "hospitalform"}))
{

    //Text Fields

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [TempData](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications) is ideal for the [Post-Redirect-Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Your Post Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string txthospitalname, int city)
{
    var hospitals = new Hospital()
    {
        Name = txthospitalname,
        FKCityID = city,
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = 1,
    };
    _db.Hospitals.Add(hospitals);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    TempData["Success"] = true;
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Your Get Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Success = TempData["Success"] as bool;
    return View();
}
```

Your View:

```
@if (ViewBag.Success != null && ViewBag.Success)
{
    <h2> Your Success Message Here</h2>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Hospital", FormMethod.Post, 
    new {enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "hospitalform"}))
{
    //Text Fields
}
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        if ('@ViewBag.Success' == "Added") {
            toastr.success("Hospital added successfull");
        }
    });

Comment: after adding this code in script it worked for me like a charm.. Thank you dear.

Comment: For ASP.NET 4.8, you will need to make the `Success` line in the `GET` Action a nullable type: `ViewBag.Success = TempData["Success"] as bool?;`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types